# Linux network briding/routing/masquerading weirdness

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot

after reading through some forums and howtos I'm lost on networking.

The challenge: I got a new device: BYD Battery Box (home energy storage system). That device can only accessed (for firmware updates and maintenance) using a proprietary software that only works when the computer running that software is connected to the wifi AP of the box (192.168.16.0/24 network). I want to access the device from my home network (192.168.2.0/24 network).

In the home network runs one ubuntu server computer that does dhcp and (filtered) dns (pihole) and other nasty things. So far I've been able to connect the ubuntu box to the wifi of the BYD box using wpa_supplicant on device wlan0. I'm able to access the IP-Adresse of the box (192.168.16.254) on the box itself.

But I cannot figure out how to make the box accessable from the whole network. Is bridging the way to go? Or static routing? Masquerading?

The more I read the more I'm lost ;-)

What should I do the achieve what I'm looking for? Note: the inet Router/default GW on the network does not have any advanced capabilities (like static routing). One more bad thing: the byd maintainence software has 192.168.16.254 hardcoded (could be changed in hex editor).

Any help/advice is highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: sketch:]

Answer (score 0):

So what I get now.

1. Your Server is connected to that battery box via wifi? Correct?
2. You want to reach that battery box from all of your clients? Correct?

Q: Is the "Server" also the default gw? I assume that, because its providing DHCP.
So this means any host in the network which does not know the subnet of your battery box will go over your default gw.

What you can do now?
I propose hiding your other hosts behind the IP of the wifi adapter of the Server. This way you can reach it. You can use SNAT for this, means your SRC IP will be translated to the IP of the wifi adapter.

so it would be something like this

## iptables -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.16.254/32 -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source (IP ADDR OF YOUR wlan0. Guess its 192.168.16.1)

Next time when you draw a network topology. Also write down the IPs of the devices itself

like this:

(HOST A).1 -------------------- 192.168.0.0/24 ---------------- .254 (HOST B)

Makes it easier to help and to understand the adressing scheme.

hope this helps.

cheers

fastboot

EDIT: according to your answer. Since you don't want to expose the network to any hosts in your network, easiest way would be to do this with a static route on your router. Point the network 192.168.16.0/24 to your servers LAN IP(Because the router won't know that WIfi I guess. Or if you don't want to add the whole network, you can add a host route as well.

So connection would be something like this then

anyhost <-> Router <-> Server <-WIFI-> battery box

This is for L3! Surely L2 would work different since LAN is in the same subnet and no need to go over the router itself. This way the the battery box would all the time see the IP of the Server, insted of the real IP of the requesting host.

EDIT_2: I recommend as reference: https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html
It's very well written. If you have any further questions, just ask. :)

Comment: Thanks fastboot.

Problem: the ubuntu server isn't the default gw on the network. The default gw is the dsl router (192.168.2.1).

Do I need to change the network config to make the ubuntu server (192.168.2.2) the default gw of all other network clients and forward from there to the dsl router?

Comment: See above. No you don't need this. It's considerable, because this way you could do a lot of more magic with iptables and filtering itself. But I don't recommend that.
If you wan to do this. I propose to give a different subnet between Router and Server. A transfer network for example with /30 (4 IPs, 1 Network, 1 Broadcast Address and 2 usuable IPs for router and Server. Like 10.0.0.0/30. network .0, Router .1, Server .2, BC .3) default gw would be then the server. And point the server to the router as default gw. But in fact no need to change your setup.